# empty Datagridview in virtualmode with millions of rows slows

Tags: datagridview, performance, virtualmode

I am trying to create datagridview connected to sqlserver.
But it seems that even in simple datagridview cannot handle quickly millions
of rows. And so  **scrolled to upper rows datagridview updates noticably
faster, that scrolled down to last row**.

The effect can be seen:

```
    Public Class Form1   
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.
EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   DataGridView1.VirtualMode = True
   DataGridView1.RowCount = 10000000
   DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
End Sub


Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e
As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.
CellValueNeeded

e.Value = 1
   End Sub
End Class
```

''form contains datagridview with 3 columns

Is there some workaround?

Comment: Don't handle millions of rows.

Answer (score 1):

you should set to false any options regarding auto sizing of rows and columns and use a cache for your row data (of size about 2 times the actual number of rows displayed in the grid) see msdn